# How to update a single user's groups with WSO2 SCIM 2.0 REST API?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to replace a single user's group with a completely new set of groups. I am able to add user to a group and remove user from a group with https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/apidocs/SCIM2-endpoints/#!/operations#GroupsEndpoint#patchGroup API.

However, I want to completely replace the groups entirely with a new array, so I don't have to individually add/remove user from each group. I have tried using the following request

POST {url}/scim2/Users/{groupID}

with the following POST body

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
    ],
    "Operations": [
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "value": {
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "display": "group1",
                        "value": "092555e8-1636-4642-924e-27aef49757fe"
                    },
                    {
                        "display": "group2",
                        "value": "b0d42429-67e2-4447-9846-2b001add431f"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the response returned was

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
    ],
    "detail": "Error in performing the add operation",
    "status": "500"
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST {url}/scim2/Users/{groupID}` request won't work since there is no such endpoint. I think you tried to replace the `groups` attribute of the user resource by a patch operation. If so, the request would be `PATCH {url}/scim2/Users/{userId}`.
However, that doesn't work due to the following reasons.

1. According to the SCIM specification(see groups description in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-4.1.2) groups attribute of the user should be managed using the /Groups endpoint.

   *Direct group membership indicates that the user is directly associated with the group and **SHOULD indicate that clients may modify membership through the "Group" resource**.*
2. Also groups attribute of User resource is a `ReadOnly` attribute. Therefore, it can't be modified using `PATCH /User` endpoint. (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-8.7.1) Schema definition in WSO2 IS: https://github.com/wso2/charon/blob/f5229c1ed55548d74b833e1a04656ac695899d9b/modules/charon-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/charon3/core/schema/SCIMSchemaDefinitions.java#L791

Therefore you have to use `PATCH /Groups` endpoint to modify the groups details of the user.

Comment: This is the solution which we are also using in our project. But we are currently facing an issue with this approach. Inorder to add a new role to a user replacing the old one, we are currently adding the role followed by deleting the existing role (which finally works like an update ) . It was working smoothly for past 1 year. But as the number of users increased , the patch /Groups is not responding and the api gets timeout error. Can you suggest a way to update role of a single user without affecting the entire group? @anuradha

Comment: If you could give a solution, pls feel free to add it as an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65887494/how-to-update-a-single-users-groups-with-wso2-scim-rest-api-without-using-patch

Answer (score 1):

`POST {url}/scim2/Users/{groupID}`
Such an endpoint doesn't exist. You might have to stick to the `/Groups PATCH` operation to add or remove roles from users. (Iterate the request programatically in this case.)

Comment: Thats the only solution which we also figured out . But it has its drawbacks if the user base is high. Could you pls read my question If you could give a solution, pls feel free to add it as an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65887494/how-to-update-a-single-users-groups-with-wso2-scim-rest-api-without-using-patch and come up with any solution which helps solving the problem ? @Nipun Thanks in advance